# Tableau - How to view time column up to 3 digit milliseconds?

Tags: datetime, tableau-api, time-format

I am working with a dataset in Tableau where I have a column [Time], which holds 'mm:ss:SSS' (minutes:seconds.milliseconds (up to 3 digits)).

However, when I cast the column to time data type, the digits truncate and does not allow me to see the milliseconds.

Does anyone know if Tableau supports 3 digit milliseconds? And how to do it?

**What I want to achieve:**

Column: 1:27.452 (string)
Output: 0:01:27:452 (hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds up to 3 digits)

**What I get:**

Column: 1:27.452
Calculated field: **DATEPARSE("mm:ss.SSS", [Time])
Output: 0:01:27

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to  [Tableau documentation](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/dates_custom_date_formats.htm) you could use miliseconds with `000` format.

Comment: Thank you!! The documentation did help me to visualize miliseconds in the column; however, these miliseconds are all set as .000, because they were not parsed correctly from the start. That's the part where I am having trouble.

Comment: After following your suggestion, I additionally changed my calculated field to  **DATEPARSE("mm:ss.AAA", [Time]) and it is now working! Thanks for the help!! :)